# CSS Layout Button/text Trouble

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a layout - picture this:

I've got a rounded grey box with some text, and 2 buttons inside it.

The grey box is the width of the page (about 900px), and the buttons are 250px each.

The text is 300px wide.

I want the two buttons to align right, and the text to align left.

This is my basic layout:

```
<div id="grey_box">

<p class="text"></p>

<div class="buttons">

<a class="button1"></a>

<a class="button2"></a>

</div>

</div>
```

For some reason, the text always appears above the buttons, i want them all to be center of the box (vertical wise) the grey box is about 80px in height.

Here's my CSS:

```
#grey_box {
    height: 80px;
    background: #f4f4f4;    
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

.text {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}

.buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    width: 450px;
}
```

Underneath is a rough idea of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Where are you putting your text for in the buttons in your code?

Comment: Sorry, the above is just a rough idea of what is happening in my code, in practice the width is not actually exceeding the total. Again, the above is a rough idea, so text on buttons etc is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your total width exceeds the container width, so the buttons jump to the next line below the paragraph. You need to factor in the border, margin, and padding when calculating width.

See this corrected **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rTKkW/1/)**

```
#grey_box {
    height: 80px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
.text {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
.buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 450px;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but your elements are too wide for their container.  The simplest way to get elements to be vertically centered within a container of a specific size is to use the `display: table` properties.

http://tinker.io/e4409/1

```
#grey_box {
    height: 80px;
    background: #f4f4f4;    
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    display: table;
}

.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 450px;
}

.buttons {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    /*text-align: right;*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because the buttons div you have is 450 pixels wide, and has 20px margin to the right. The available space : 900px is insufficient because you effectively need 450+450+20 pixels of space in the gray box. Also, the buttons need 500px of space, since they are 250px each. Try increasing the width of gray box to 1000, or increase the size of buttons div and reduce the size of text div.

Alternatively, you can also use a table, and format each of these in separate table cells.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align=left width=300> Text here</td>
<td align=right width=250> Button 1</td>
<td align=left width=250> Button 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```